# why there is no ArithmeticException( divide by zero) when both values are double?

Tags: java, android, exception, math

Seen source code of Double.java and some constants are like

```
/**
 * Constant for the Not-a-Number (NaN) value of the {@code double} type.
 */
public static final double NaN = 0.0 / 0.0;

/**
 * Constant for the positive infinity value of the {@code double} type.
 */
public static final double POSITIVE_INFINITY = 1.0 / 0.0;

/**
 * Constant for the negative infinity value of the {@code double} type.
 */
public static final double NEGATIVE_INFINITY = -1.0 / 0.0;
```

but I wonder why it is not throwing ArithmeticException(divide by zero)?

and I have tried

```
 public static final int VALUE = 0/0;
```

now it's throwing Exception but when I say

```
 public static final double VALUE = 0d/0d;
```

it is not throwing exception...

What's the magic of `Double` and why it is not throwing Exception?

Comment: because with double 0 is never 0 and it is typically expressed by a NaN

Comment: Probably because 0d is not exactly 0, but a value very close to it

Comment: @blackbelt can you explain clearly please... if 0 is not 0 when it is double, then what will be the value for 0?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642601/dividing-a-double-by-zero-in-java

Comment: @GopalRao see Stephen answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "magic" is that Java floating point representations are based on the [IEE 754 floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard.  This has a special value (NaN) that denotes the "indefinite value" that you get when zero is divided by zero.  (There are also values that represent positive and negative infinity; e.g. `1.0 / 0.0` gives `INF` - positive infinity.)

This is covered in the Java Language Specification; see sections [§4.2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) which discusses the representations and [§4.2.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4) which discusses how arithmetic works.

---

Note that the same "magic" applies to `float`, `double`, `Float` and `Double`.

Answer (score 1):

Because something that is undefined in the number system cannot be obviously represented. "Undefined" is not a number (NaN) and double/float have NaN to indicate that.

[IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

"arithmetic formats: sets of binary and decimal floating-point data, which consist of finite numbers (including signed zeros and subnormal numbers), infinities, and special "not a number" values (NaNs)"

Comment: Ermm ... NaN does not represent infinity.  INF represents infinity.  Zero divided by zero is "indefinite".

Answer (score 1):

Doubles in Java (and some but not all other languages) support values that are NaN (Not a number).

Operations like a division by 0 will give you a double which is NaN.

Any operation involving a NaN will also result in a NaN.

Wikipedia has a whole page on the subject of NaN:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN